# Find Actual Width of unordered list Tree

Tags: css

[image]

I have a set of CSS which allows simple family trees to be drawn using unordered lists.

This works well so long as the ul.tree is narrower than the width of the screen at which point it does an untidy wrap.  To avoid this I have used the following:

```
#treewrapper {
 margin: 10px; padding: 20px;  width: auto;  white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: scroll;   overflow-x: scroll;
}
#tree {width: 5000px;}
```

How ever this means you get a huge #tree area even when the tree is actually narrower than the the current width of #treewrapper.

My first thought was to find the width of the ul element and change the width of ul.tree to match using javascript once the page is rendered,  but when I look at the width of ul it appears to be the width of #tree minus the padding.

Setting #tree width to auto simply results in a wrapped ul.tree when the screen is narrow.

Is there a simple way in CSS (or javascript) to get #tree to be wide enough?

Live example with #tree set to Auto can be seen at http://www.rjt.org.uk/m/example/index.html

Comment: i don't know if posting this as an answer, but adding `.tree ul {padding-left:0}` (to remove default browser padding) i can see the correct width on `.tree > ul>li:first-child` (the main li containing the whole tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get the width is by using javascipt and `.offsetWidth`. Here is an example:

```
document.getElementById('tree').offsetWidth;
```

Though you can just use css to include the padding by using:

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

Because when you use block elements it picks up the padding as well

Answer (score 0):

Change the width of `#treewrapper`, `.tree` and `.tree ul` to `width:100%;`. Should fix your problem.